# Adding underscore to variable

Tags: ruby

I have a variable `title`. It can look like:

```
title = 'One two three'
```

Is it possible to replace the blanks with underscores?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure! What you want is either `gsub` or `gsub!` depending on your use case.

```
title = "One two three".gsub(/\s+/, "_")
```

will substitute any whitespace character with an underscore in the string and will store the string into `title`

if you already have title with the string stored then you can do

```
title.gsub!(/\s+/, "_")
```

and it will do the same substitution in title.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the `gsub` method:

```
title = 'One two three'.gsub(/ /, '_')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
title = 'One two three'.tr(" ", "_")
```

Answer (score -2):

You can also split the string, automatically removing extra white space with `.split` and then rejoin the words with `.join('_')`

So `title.split.join('_')`

This has the benefit of not putting underscores or hyphens or whatever in the place of any trailing or leading spaces.